# Unity Android keyboard text shows white text on white background

Tags: android, text, unity-game-engine, keyboard

I'm creating a Unity application with textfields in it.

In the beginning there were no problems with the textfield inputs. I could write and texts would show nicely on the keyboards line

Then I've added some assets which altered the manifest. I don't know which line but I have multiple (5 exactly) AndroidManifest files in my Unity project and I'm facing this problem

When I'm typing with keyboard, text does get typed but it has white color on white background. I can select the text, edit the text but its bad for user to use a keyboard like that

What should I do? Thanks a lot!

ps. This problem does not occur on iOS devices. Only on Android

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We experienced the same problem but we were able to fix it by adding the following property:

```
android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector"
```

To the application tag in the file

```
Plugins\Android\AndroidManifest.xml
```

Eg:

```
<application android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector"...
```

I'm not sure how that applies to having multiple manifests but perhaps only one of them has the application tag.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would have searched days and days without your hint ....